# How to solve for delimter conflicts

Tags: pandas, delimiter, conflict

I have a large .TXT file which is delimited by ";". Unfortunately some of my values contain ";" aswell, which in that case is not a delimiter but recognized as delimiter by pandas. Becasue of this I have difficulties reading the .txt. files into pandas because some lines have more columns than the others. Background: I am trying to combine several .txt files into 1 dataframe and get the following error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 21 fields in line 443, saw 22.

So when checking line 443 I saw indeed that that line had 1 more instance of ";" because it was part of one of the values.

Reproduction:

Text file 1:

```
1;2;3;4
23123213;23123213;23123213;23123213
123;123;123;123
123;123;123;123
1;1;1;1
123;123;123;123
12;12;12;12
3;3;3;3
```

Text file 2:

```
1;2;3;4
23123213;23123213;23123213;23123213
123;123;123;123
123;123;12;3;123
1;1;1;1
123;123;123;123
12;12;12;12
3;3;3;3
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = r'C:\Users\file'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, delimiter=';')
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I have included two text files plus my code above in my question now

Comment: if the file is not a valid csv, then fix it by string replace or regex replace, then use pandas read csv.

Comment: Thanks, then I'm afraid the best solution is to manually fix the mistake by editing the file. There is no way to unambiguously fix this in an automated way (else how to decide if `123;123;12;3;123` should be `123;123;123;123` or `123123;12;3;123` or anything else?)

Comment: What do you want to do in this case? How do you decide which value goes where? How do you know which filed has the extra delimited?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It wil indeed be challenging to decide whether a semicolon is delimiter or not (non-manual). Not sure wheter using regex (as a beginner) is worth it now, will try look in to. My approach now is to just put all text contents in to excel and then mannually adjust it. And then put them back in CSV format.

Comment: A regular expression won't help if there's not a clear "regular" rule to clean the data. It won't make it any easier to know which are real separators and which are not. It might make more sense to go back and figure out how the data got messy in the first place. Maybe it makes sense to use a different delimiter like a tab for the data.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I am not really sure how the data is exctracted, but I think it was a download from SAP. I will check for future reports if there is a possibility to change the delimiter to a pipe character for example. Thanks anayway everyone for the quick advice!